# Dialogflow Fulfillment LINE custom payload

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating Dialogflow fulfillment webhook and use https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs

I want to use quick reply in LINE and use [Suggestion](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/src/rich-responses/suggestions-response.js), but it is not working as I want it like this [quick reply](https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/using-quick-reply/). Then I decide to try Custom Payload, but it is not working.

My code is like this

```js
function testQuickReplyHandler(agent) {
        let payload = {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Select your favorite food category or send me your location!",
                    "quickReply": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "action",
                                "action": {
                                    "type": "message",
                                    "label": "Sushi",
                                    "text": "Sushi"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "action",
                                "action": {
                                    "type": "message",
                                    "label": "Tempura",
                                    "text": "Tempura"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "action",
                                "action": {
                                    "type": "location",
                                    "label": "Send location"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]};
        agent.add(new Payload('LINE', payload));
    }
```

Am I missing something? I also try removing "messages" field, but also not working

Answer (score 1):

```
agent.add(new Payload('LINE', payload)); => agent.add(new Payload(agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE, payload));
```

Or any payload you like